# How to verify and publish contract source code created from contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

I hope to help me about some mistake.
I take this all work in bsctestnetwork.
I created stablePool contract from stablePoolFactory contract.
So I need to verify and publish this contract, i.e stablePool.
but I dont know how to get source code of stablePool.
I think maybe it need to handle on remix, I can't do it. I don't know what to do and what happens.
address is following:

stablePoolFactory: `0x465f877942109dbfcfddB36EDD8398c11De5ED95`

created stablePool: `0x5f36963bbEB107fB6D63C6B9951e080Ea578230A`

Comment: Where did you get the `stablePoolFactory` contract from? please add details, share links to source codes, and annotate your code properly (format code with `, use lists to increase readability, etc.)

Comment: Mr, Paul, thank you for response me, I think you can see source code of stablePoolFactory  above cause it is already verified and published . and all of this is similar with FantOHM DAO, actually it is forked from fantohm.  but I'd like to use it in BSC network. so I need to verify and publish it in BSEtest network. thats all, thank you.

Comment: @ruslanmaxim How are you deploying the contracts? It is likely there's a plugin that will verify the contract code in the more popular block explorer.